# tikz - position text remember picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I position the text "xyz" at the top left of image1 ? Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image2) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image3) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image4) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image5) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image7) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image8) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}

    % max t = 246
    
    % image1 t=0
    \def\time1{0}
    \draw let \p1=(image1.west), \p2=(image1.east), \n1={\time1*(\x2-\x1)} in [line width=0.5mm] ($(image1.north west)+(0,0.1)$)--($(image3.north east)+(\n1,0.1)$);
    \begin{scope}[x={(image1.north west)},y={(image1.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south west,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {xyz};
    \end{scope}


\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just use `\node[anchor=south west, draw, fill=white] at (image1.north west) {xyz};`. For the line, `\draw[line width=0.5mm] ([yshift=0.1cm]image1.north west) -- ([yshift=0.1cm]image3.north east);` would be enough. No `scope` or `let` needed.

Comment: With `x` and `y` you set the units of the *x* and *y* axis. What you probably wanted to do is `shift={(image1.north west)}`. But as pointed out above, there is no need to use this.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you

Comment: When there is only one node in a tikzpicture, its coordinates are irrelevant.   The tikzpicture itself will be positioned relative to the bounding box and baseline (see page 129).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to declare `subcaptions` I don't think that you need all these `subfloat`. Something similar can be done with a `matrix of nodes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=3pt,  nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=0pt}] (image){
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{example-image-a} \\};
\draw[line width=.5mm] ([yshift=1mm]image-1-1.north west) coordinate (aux)--([yshift=1mm]image-1-3.north east);
\node[above right=1mm and 0pt of aux, draw] {xyz};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]